# Strange multi-threading output for different Platforms

Tags: multithreading, ubuntu, gcc, centos, pthreads

I executed the following code on Ubuntu 14.04 and CentOS 7 using gcc compiler but the strange thing is that it shows different output for same inputs. There are two issues that I'm unable to solve.

1. I always get 0 in sum(in main function) for the very first multiplication (1*1).
2. Completely unexpected output for Ubuntu.
   Here is the code and both the outputs.

> Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 15
struct matrix
{
    int num1, num2;
};
void* multiply(void *c);
int main()
{
    int i, j, rows, cols, a[N][N], b[N][N], sum, k, final, res[N][N],*ptr;
    pthread_t t1, t2;
    struct matrix m1;
    ptr=&sum;
    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("Enter the number of cols: ");
    scanf("%d", &cols);
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter the value at: a[%d][%d] : ", i, j);           
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter the value at: b[%d][%d] : ", i, j);           
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            final = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < rows; k++)
            {
                m1.num1 = a[i][k];
                m1.num2 = b[k][j];
                pthread_create(&t1, NULL, (void*)multiply,(void*)&m1);
                pthread_join(t1, (void**)&ptr);
                sum=*ptr;
                printf("\t%d",sum);
                final += sum;
                res[i][j] = final;
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }   
    printf("The result is :\n");
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", res[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
void* multiply(void *c)
{   
    struct matrix *m;
    m = (struct matrix *)c;
    int p = 0;
    p = m->num1 * m->num2;
    printf("\t%d * %d = %d",m->num1,m->num2,p);
    pthread_exit((void*)&p);
}
```

> Output for execution on Ubuntu

```
Enter the number of rows: 2
Enter the number of cols: 2
Enter the value at: a[0][0] : 1
Enter the value at: a[0][1] : 2
Enter the value at: a[1][0] : 3
Enter the value at: a[1][1] : 4
Enter the value at: b[0][0] : 1
Enter the value at: b[0][1] : 2
Enter the value at: b[1][0] : 3
Enter the value at: b[1][1] : 4
    1 * 1 = 1   0   2 * 3 = 6   32648
    1 * 2 = 2   32648   2 * 4 = 8   32648
    3 * 1 = 3   32648   4 * 3 = 12  32648
    3 * 2 = 6   32648   4 * 4 = 16  32648
The result is :
32648   65296   
65296   65296
```

> Output for execution on CentOS

```
Enter the number of rows: 2
Enter the number of cols: 2
Enter the value at: a[0][0] : 1
Enter the value at: a[0][1] : 2
Enter the value at: a[1][0] : 3
Enter the value at: a[1][1] : 4
Enter the value at: b[0][0] : 1
Enter the value at: b[0][1] : 2
Enter the value at: b[1][0] : 3
Enter the value at: b[1][1] : 4
    1 * 1 = 1   0   2 * 3 = 6   6
    1 * 2 = 2   2   2 * 4 = 8   8
    3 * 1 = 3   2   4 * 3 = 12  4
    3 * 2 = 6   3   4 * 4 = 16  16
The result is :
6   10  
15  22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `multiply` function is returning a pointer to a local variable `p`, and the lifetime of the local variable finishes as soon as the function ends.

The easiest solution here is not to use the return value, but to reserve a place for the result in the `struct matrix` that is passed to `multiply()`, because that structure is allocated within `main`.  Change the definition of `struct multiply`:

```
struct matrix
{
    int num1, num2;
    int product;
};
```

Change `multiply()` to put the result here:

```
void *multiply(void *c)
{   
    struct matrix *m = c;

    m->product = m->num1 * m->num2;
    printf("\t%d * %d = %d", m->num1, m->num2, m->product);
    return NULL;
}
```

Change `main()` to retrieve the result from there:

```
pthread_create(&t1, NULL, multiply, &m1);
pthread_join(t1, NULL);
sum = m1.product;
```

(Side note: that variable `sum` has a confusing name, since it doesn't hold a sum!)

Comment: But the manual page of pthread_join says that it sets the value returned by pthread_exit() to the integer pointed by ptr(ptr in my program). With that in mind shouldn't I just receive the value of p in sum if I declare ptr=&sum in beginning? I tried doing so but it didn't work. [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) is the link to that manual page.

Comment: The exit status returned by your thread isn't the integer pointer to: it's the pointer itself (a pointer to the variable `p` in `multiply()`).  That pointer value gets happily returned into `ptr` by `pthread_join()`, but it's not valid to use anymore, because the pointed-to variable `p` doesn't exist anymore.  (The *"value that the target thread supplied to `pthread_exit()`*" mentioned in the man page is a *pointer* value).

Comment: Furthermore, `ptr` gets overwritten by `pthread_join()`, so it doesn't matter what you set it to in the beginning.  It ends up pointing to `p`, but `p` isn't there anymore.

Comment: Then How is it that CentOS shows the correct output for the same code? It still doesn't explain different output for different OS. I tried it on Fedora and its working fine, just like CentOS.

Comment: It changes on different environments because that's the nature of the bug your code has - how it appears depends on how and when that memory is reused.  CentOS and Ubuntu use different versions of the C compiler and standard library.  If you look carefully you'll notice that it's buggy on CentOS too - your CentOS example output has `1 * 1 = 1   0` and `3 * 2 = 6   3` among other incorrect examples.

Comment: Your last comment along with other comments of yours!! A light bulb I just got! Thanks. Figured it out. +1 :)